# Prevent angular form from submitting if input is blank

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an Angular form inside a ng2 popup:

```
<popup>
  Sign up for our Newsletter!     <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
</button>         <input type="email"/>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
</popup>
<button class="submit" (click)="ClickButton()">Sign up for our Newsletter </button>
```

here is the onClick event function:

```
constructor(private popup:Popup) { }
  testAlert() {   ClickButton(){
    alert("Newsletter event works");    this.popup.options = {
  widthProsentage: 15,
  showButtons: false,
  header: "Sign up for our Newsletter!",
}
this.popup.show(this.popup.options);
  }
```

It works fine but I am able to submit her even if the input is blank, how can I make so that it does not submit if it is clicked empty

I tried using RegEx but it did not work

Comment: Why do you  use `(ngSubmit)` and `(click)` at the same time? where is the `onSubmit` func?

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding validation.

Something like this:

```
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label"
               for="userNameId">User Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input class="form-control"
                 id="userNameId"
                 type="text"
                 placeholder="User Name (required)"
                 required
                 (ngModel)="userName"
                 name="userName"
                 #userNameVar="ngModel"
                 [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': (userNameVar.touched || userNameVar.dirty) && !userNameVar.valid }" />
          <span class="invalid-feedback">
            <span *ngIf="userNameVar.errors?.required">
              User name is required.
            </span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

You can then disable the submit button if the fields are not valid:

```
         <button class="btn btn-primary"
                  type="submit"
                  style="width:80px;margin-right:10px"
                  [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">
            Log In
          </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**(ngSubmit)** is built-in event emitter inside of Angular **ngForm** and is directly related to ***button*** element which is kind of a trigger for form submission.
Therefore, as *lealceldeiro* said, you only need **onSubmit** function and button intended for submission **inside** of your form tag.

Please provide live demo so we can see the whole file (.ts particularly).
Setting the validation properly depends on what kind of forms you're going to use (template or ReactiveForms).

[See more](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm) about proper ngForm usage in official documentation.